# How can I add the contents of a plain text (or HTML) file to a Virtuoso triplestore?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I have a virtuoso triplestore that contains values like "/path/to/my/plain-text-file.txt". I'd like to have Virtuoso read those files, and then index their contents, so that I could query it somehow with SPARQL. Is that possible? And if so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Other than that, the only other thing that I can think of now, you could add the whole content of a file in a single RDF string literal value and add it somehow to the existing RDF data via an additional triples. Then you could enable Virtuoso fulltext index and at least search for tokens occurring in those indexed long string literals. Is that what you meant? I guess not, but who knows. For documents like HTML indeed you have to pre-process the file and extract the content with some other lib like JSoup etc

Comment: @AKSW - "Virtuoso just reads RDF data" is inaccurate. Virtuoso is a multi-model DBMS, and there are various ways to satisfy the poster's goal. These include loading the files into Virtuoso's WebDAV, and setting up a bunch of `owl:sameAs` relations between the WebDAV resource locations and the `/path/to/my/plain-text-file.txt` literals, among other possibilities. The way that makes the most sense will depend on many factors, including the number of files involved, the number of paths involved, the sizes of these files, etc.

Comment: @Jonathan - As with your other Virtuoso-specific question(s), I suggest you come to the [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com/), where you'll find many other Virtuoso users as well as members of the Development team, some of whom may well have already done just what you're wanting to figure out.

Comment: @TallTed ok, so I was wrong and indeed will delete my comments. Nevertheless, the answer should provided here, otherwise we can forward any Virtuoso specific question to the mailing list in the future which is fine but should be mentioned in the `virtuoso` tag. or somewhere. People asking similar questions tend to search here first and then stop before getting to other vendor specific sources.

Comment: @AKSW - I've added the Community Forum link to the tag info ([pending peer review](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4477540)). There isn't "one true answer" to this question, hence my directing the OP to a conversationally-oriented site, so more can be learned about their needs and resources, and relevant guidance provided.

Comment: @Jonathan - [Enhancements the Virtuoso Sponger brings to SPARQL](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtSpongerLinkedDataHooksIntoSPARQL) may provide sufficient suggestions for you to work through on your own ... or may lead you to more questions, whether more suitable for here or the Virtuoso-specific sites.